# How to mark secret as optional in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

From the docs:

> Secrets must be created before they are consumed in pods as environment variables unless they are marked as optional. References to Secrets that do not exist will prevent the pod from starting.

How to mark secret as optional?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

What you're looking for is

```
  - name: ENV_NAME
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: <secrets name>
        key: <secrets key>
        optional: true
```

You can find type definition [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/e9e190c57c61a88a2ba96c4b0688b8eb3a8945a8/pkg/apis/core/types.go#L1762)

Edit: similarly for `envFrom`

```
envFrom:
- secretRef:
    name: secname
    optional: true
```

Comment: after setting option: true for the secret, existing secret got deleted, how come? 
idea is if secret exists - then it mounts env from the secret, if not then do not throw error. 
why is this strange behavior?

Comment: @user2700022 For comparison, adding `optional: true` to the config for my secret had the effect described by the answer, and did not cause the existing secret to be deleted. I'm guessing some other mechanism caused the secret deletion. (Possibly due to a typo of `option: true` instead of `optional: true`?)