# Optional volume/secret volume in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I'd like to mount volume if it exists. For example:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: mypod
    image: redis
    volumeMounts:
    - name: foo
      mountPath: "/etc/foo"
  volumes:
  - name: foo
    secret:
      secretName: mysecret
```

is the example from the documentation. However if the secret `mysecret` doesn't exist I'd like to skip mounting. That is optimistic/optional mount point.

Now it stalls until the secret is created.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mark secret as optional in kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48208705/how-to-mark-secret-as-optional-in-kubernetes)

Comment: Similar but different

Answer (score 21, accepted):

secret and configmap volumes can be marked optional, and result in empty directories if the associated secret or configmap doesn't exist, rather than blocking pod startup

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: mypod
      image: redis
      volumeMounts:
        - name: foo
          mountPath: /etc/foo
  volumes:
    - name: foo
      secret:
        secretName: mysecret
        optional: true
```

Comment: Saw it in the Kubernetes documentation but that missed an example (only says mark it as "optional"). Thanks!

Comment: If the Pod starts and the configmap does not exist, it results in an empty directory. What happens when the configmap appears after the Pod successfully starts? Is it the ConfigMap then mounted?

Answer (score 3):

While this `optional` logic exists for env variables, it's not available for volumes as far as I am aware. It also seems a bit problematic as your infrastructure stops being immutable, depending on sequence for creation in kube you get a different application state. Rather then looking for this I woud suggest utilising a higher level templating features like the ones available in `Helm` so that you can do :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: mypod
    image: redis
{{- if .Values.mysecret.enabled }}
    volumeMounts:
    - name: foo
      mountPath: "/etc/foo"
  volumes:
  - name: foo
    secret:
      secretName: mysecret
{{- end }}
```

And then if you provision with `--set mysecret.enabled=true` you will get the volume declared and with `--set mysecret.enabled=false` it will not be declared so it will not attempt to mount it at all

Comment: This can't handle the case where neither the author of the Container being deployed nor the author of the Values for that Container know if the ultimate users will actually deploy a Volume (such as might contain custom ConfigMap file content).

The intent is to inform the redeployable Container that sometimes, at run time, it might find a Volume present and should then mount that. It should not fail to deploy if the Volume is absent.